# How well does $\mathrm{Zi}(x)=\frac1e\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^k}{kk!\phi(k)}$, with $\phi(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^k}$, approximate $\pi(x)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

It is well known that: $$\mathrm{Li}(x)=\int_2^x \frac{1}{\ln(t)}~dt$$

is an extraordinarily good approximation to the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ and is currently the best known approximation.

I constructed a function asymptotic to the prime counting function $\pi(x):$

$$\mathrm{Zi}(x)=\frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^k}{kk!\phi(k)}$$

where I invented the function:

$$  \phi(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^k}  $$

This $\mathrm{Zi}(x)$ is a fantastic approximation to $\pi(x).$ I believe the constant $1/e$ is optimal.

> Just how good is it?

Numerical analysis suggests that $\mathrm{Li(10^{17})}-\mathrm{Zi(10^{17})}\approx 40$ where $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ is the offset logarithmic integral. This means $\mathrm{Zi}(x)$ beats $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ by $40$ units at that value. Numerical analysis also suggests that $\mathrm{Li}(x)-\mathrm{Zi}(x)\sim \ln x$ which of course could fail eventually in light of Skewe's number.

> Is $\mathrm{Zi}(x)$ *on average* better than $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ at approximating $\pi(x)?$ That is does $\mathrm{Zi}(x)$ reduce the mean error even more so than $\mathrm{Li}(x)?$

Comment: $Li(x)$ us a good approximation for $\pi(x)$ as $x\to\infty$, but by my calculations $Li(x)$ is a much better approximation than $Zi(x)$ even at $x=10^{17}$. How many sum terms did you evaluate in your formulas for $Zi(x)$ and $\phi(k)$?

Comment: I used $n,k$ up to $100$

Comment: @StevenClark did you forget the $1/e$ multiplier out front?

Comment: No, I just didn't evaluate as many $n$ and $k$ terms in the two sums which I now see makes a big difference. It does appear $Zi(x)$ is a better approximation for $\pi(x)$ than $Li(x)$ at $x=10^{17}$, but I believe the Riemann R function $R(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\, \text{li}\left(x^{1/n}\right)$ is a much better approximation.

Comment: Related: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramSeries.html

Comment: @StevenClark I believe that $R(x)$ is a better approximation up to a certain magnitude but it's been proven worse than $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ infinitely often.

Comment: Anyway, my question specifically asks about comparing Li(x) and Zi(x)

Comment: @Gary But how related is $\mathrm{Zi}(x)$ to the Gram series? One has to ask

Comment: If $R(x)$ is worse than $Li(x)$ infinitely often, is it not also better infinitely often, or alternatively is $Li(x)$ not also worse than $R(x)$ infinitely often? It appears $Zi(x)$ is an approximation to the Gram series which is equivalent to $R(x)$.

Comment: It is my understanding that the Gram series being better than Li(x) is illusory. It does not reduce the mean error of that of Li(x) and pi(x)

Comment: @geocalc33 I was wondering about that, so thanks for the comment. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @geocalc33 I'm really interested in seeing a proof of your result, will you provide it in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that

$$Zi(x)=\frac{1}{e} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log^k(x)}{k k! \phi(k)}\tag{1}$$

is an approximation to the Gram series

$$G(x)=1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log^k(x)}{k k! \zeta (k+1)}\tag{2}$$

which is equivalent to the Riemann R function

$$R(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \text{li}\left(x^{1/n}\right)\tag{3}$$

and I see no reason to believe $Zi(x)$ is a better approximation to $\pi(x)$ than $\text{li}(x)$ or $G(x)=R(x)$.

---

The following discrete plot illustrates $\frac{1}{e\, \phi(k)}$ (orange points) seems to quickly converge to $\frac{1}{\zeta (k+1)}$ (blue points) as $k$ increases (since both seem to quickly converge to $1$) where the sum in the formula for $\phi(k)$ is evaluated over the first $100$ terms.

[image: Figure (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $\frac{1}{e\, \phi(k)}$ (orange) and $\frac{1}{\zeta (k+1)}$ (blue)

Comment: Note also that $$
{\rm Li}(x) = \gamma  + \log \log x + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\log^k x }}{{kk!}}} .
$$

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer